# React: How might I implement an event listener method to remove a child Component from a parent

Tags: reactjs, react-component

*Please find my codebases below that are relevant to my question.*

I am having trouble trying to develop a `discard()` function that would remove a card on the browser upon double-clicking the card you desire to discard. The commented-out discard function works correctly, but only discards the last card in your hand whereas I am trying to make it to where, with a user's double-clicking on a specific card, that card would be removed giving the user more liberty to choose the card he/she wishes to discard.

Any assistance, guidance, or reference material would be greatly appreciated!

**Parent Component: `PlayersHand.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import './PlayersHand.css';
import { currentGameDeck, playerOneHand } from '../Logic/game_logic';
import PlayingCard from '../PlayingCard/PlayingCard';



class PlayersHand extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      cards: playerOneHand,
      setOne: [],
      setTwo: [],
      setThree: []
    }
    this.draw = this.draw.bind(this);
    //this.discard = this.discard.bind(this);
  }

  draw() {
    let newCard = currentGameDeck.shift();
    this.setState({ cards: [...this.state.cards, newCard] })
  }

  handleDiscard = id => {
    let currentArray = [...this.state.cards]
    console.log(currentArray)
    let discardedCard = currentArray.findIndex(card => card.id === id);
    if (discardedCard === -1) {
      return
    }
    let newArray = currentArray.splice(discardedCard, 1);
    this.setState({ cards: newArray })
  }

  /* discard() {
    let currentArray = [...this.state.cards]
    let discardedCard = currentArray.pop();
    let newArray = currentArray.filter(card => {
      return card !== discardedCard
    })
    this.setState({ cards: [...newArray] })
  } */

  render() {
    let handOfCards = this.state.cards.map((card, i) =>
    <PlayingCard
    card={card}
    key={'card_' + i}
    handleDiscard={this.handleDiscard}
    />
    )

    console.log(this.state.cards);
    
    return(
      <>
        <div className="handful-of-cards">
          {handOfCards}
        </div>

        <h2>Your current hand of cards!</h2>

        <div className="card-play-options">
          <button
          onClick={this.draw}
          >
            Draw Card
          </button>
          <button
          onClick={this.discard}
          >
            Discard Card
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="sets-row">
          <section className="first-set">

          </section>
          <section className="second-set">

          </section>
          <section className="third-set">

          </section>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default PlayersHand;
```

---

---

**Child Component: `PlayingCard.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import './PlayingCard.css';



class PlayingCard extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleDoubleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleDoubleClick = () => {
        console.log(`${this.props.card.id}`)
        this.props.handleDiscard(`${this.props.card.id}`)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <img
            src={`./cards/${this.props.card.desc}.png`}
            alt={`${this.props.card.suit} ${this.props.card.number}`}
            number={this.props.card.number}
            suit={this.props.card.suit}
            value={this.props.card.value}
            id={this.props.card.id}
            className="card"
            onDoubleClick={this.handleDoubleClick}
            />
        )
    }
  }
  
  export default PlayingCard;
```

Comment: You can assign cards a unique id, and use these ids on the event to determine which card to remove

Comment: @ImanpalSingh

If I understand you correctly, my use of `id={this.props.card.id` is redundant and I should rely on the `key` value instead to delete a given card?

Comment: you should use as a `key={'card_'.card.id}`, and check when getting the index if card.id is the same type, because in the double-click function you convert it to a string.

Comment: You are calling `this.discard` on a button and there is no connection between cards & that button. Do u want to call discard function from `handleDoubleClick()` funtion?